# Which reference for [Required]

Tags: entity-framework-6, xaf

In Dev Express Xaf, should I be using 
DevExpress.ExpressApp.Model.Required  or System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute  for the [Required] attribute inside my business classes?

[Later note]
I should have clarified whether it was my intent to allow the attribute to be nullable.  It turns out that If I don't want it to be nullable then I need the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RuleRequiredFieldAttribute

the full path being - DevExpress.Persistent.Validation.RuleRequiredFieldAttribute

Comment: See also Dennis's answer at https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T259215